# Connect to S3 Web Console with Access and Secret Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3

Is it possible to authenticate in the Amazon S3 console (https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com) using an access key/secret key pair? It looks like it only accepts user credentials. If not, is there any web access method using these keys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS uses different types of credentials for different types of access.

Access key and Secret key are meant for programmatic access only.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/security-creds.html#aws-sec-cred-access-ref